# SOAP UI Request XML Values are not Binding to the JAVA Request Object in JAVA

Tags: java, web-services, spring-boot, soap, soapui

While testing SOAP Web Service using SOAP UI, SOAP request xml values are not binding to the Java request Object and coming as null values.

Please find the code as below:

```
@PayloadRoot(namespace = NAMESPACE_URI, localPart = "UserList")
@ResponsePayload
public JAXBElement<UserListResponse> UserListRequest(@RequestPayload JAXBElement<UserListRequest> request) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Enters into UserList()");
    try {
        UserListRequest userListRequest = request.getValue();//Giving UserListRequest@2                 
        System.out.println("Number:"+userListRequest.getXMLRequest().getNumber());//Getting Number is null even passing passing in SOAP UI

    //As i am not getting why soap Ui values are not binding and object reference is coming to userListRequest.

        } catch(Exception e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
          }
        return null;
}
```

Request XML in SOAP UI:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:prim="http://COM.SERVICES.WebServices/UserServices">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <prim:UserList>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <prim:XMLRequest>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <prim:Header>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <prim:MessageID>2</prim:MessageID>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <prim:CorrelationID>2</prim:CorrelationID>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <prim:SystemID>2</prim:SystemID>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <prim:RequestorID>2</prim:RequestorID>
            </prim:Header>
            <prim:Reference>C</prim:Reference>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <prim:Number>1120521877477751</prim:Number>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <prim:Usercount>51</prim:Usercount>
         </prim:XMLRequest>
      </prim:UserList>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I have generated classes using WSDL and mapping the Service operation to end point like as same above code.So without JAXBElement method is not invoking.

when am trying to get the values which are passed in SOAP UI , getting as Null.
[Please see debugger mode screen shot as all values are coming as null.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8RGUr.png)

Can anyone please suggest on this.

Comment: try to print the Soapexception, maybe there is any problem getting response from Soap

Comment: How i can print the SOAP Exception. Please help me on this. @rencinas

Comment: You need to add it inside of a try/catch, something like this: `try{}catch(ServerSOAPFaultException soap){soap.printStackTrace();}` and you must to get the response from the server inside of this try/catch

Comment: It's not throwing any exception and it's  simply giving value as null. thanks @rencinas

Comment: It looks like userListRequest is a JAXB element.  In your definition of userListRequest, do you have a getXMLRequest method on it, which in turn can call getNumber()?  As with your other similar question, use the debugger to interrogate the request variable so you can properly see the methods and properties that are accessible.

Comment: Yes, I have debugged but all values are coming as null. But i didn't understand why all values are coming as null.As i am doing any mistake. Can you please check and help me on this. Thanks @ChrisAdams

Comment: I don’t think the request parameter can be null, otherwise UserListRequest userListRequest = request.getValue() would throw an error and you wouldn’t even reach the line that you are asking about.  All I can suggest is to use a debugger and interrogate the request parameter coming in. Then see if userRequest contain anything other than null.  There’s too little of your code for me to be any more helpful.

Comment: I have attached screenshot of debugger mode as all values are coming as null. Please check and help me on this as i ma not getting why the values are coming as null. @Chris Adams